# Android wrong cycle "for" count

Tags: android

I have function

```
public ArrayList<String> vyberNahodnaPismena() {
    String[] seznamPismen = {"A", "Á", "B", "C", "Č", "D", "Ď", "E", "Ě", "É", "F", "G", "H", "I", "Í", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "Ó", "P", "Q", "R", "Ř", "S", "Š", "T", "Ť", "U", "Ú", "Ů", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Ý", "Z", "Ž"};
    ArrayList<String> nahodnaPismena = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(seznamPismen));
    ArrayList<String> pismena = new ArrayList<String>();
    pismena.addAll(rozlozSlovoNaPismena(ziskejHadanku(ziskejAktualniCisloHadanky())));
    Random nahodneCislo = new Random();
    // value of pismena.size() is 5 for now
    for(int i = 0; i < (44 - pismena.size()); i++) {
        pismena.add(nahodnaPismena.get(nahodneCislo.nextInt(nahodnaPismena.size())));
        System.out.println("i:"+i);
    }
    long seed = System.nanoTime();
    Collections.shuffle(pismena, new Random(seed));
    System.out.println("size"+pismena.size());
    return pismena;
}
```

which should chose random chars (strings) and put them to ArrayList. Value pismena.size()
I get to cycle "for" = 5.
44 - 5 = 39.
So final size of "pismena" should be 38, am I right ? But size is 25 instead. How is it possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You're adding elements and the list size is in the stop condition. I'd sugest you get the size once and use it in the condition without calling `size()` again and again.

Comment: Yes, you are right. My stupid mistake... Thanks you.

Comment: Sure, but I can set it after 5 minutes from answer.